# How to check if ANY element inside a Python Object is empty

Tags: python, arrays, object, key-value, is-empty

I have an array of objects:

```
 dataArray = [{thing1: foo, thing2: baa, thing3:foobaa},{thing1: doo, thing2: daa, thing3: doodaa}]
```

Which I am editing in a function by iterating over the lines:

```
  for obj in dataArray:
      DO STUFF
```

I want to skip the whole object if ANY of the values are empty.

e.g. if

```
  dataArray['thing2'] == ''
```

Is there a way to generalise this without having to iterate though all the keys in the obj?

Comment: On some level -- iteration is required. You could perhaps hide that iteration in a call to `any()`  (a python function whose name appears in the title of your question).

Comment: `if any(v == '' for v in obj.values()): continue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all` function for this task following way, consider following example

```
d = {"A": "abc", "B": "", "C": "ghi"}
any_empty = not all(d.values())
print(any_empty)
```

output:

```
True
```

I used `all` here to detect if all values are truth-y then negate is at will be `False` if any value is `False`. Note that this is actually sensitive to `bool(value)` so it will also detect `None`, `False` and so on, so please consider if this is acceptable in your case.